# How to show a UISegementedControl over a UIImageView/UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I tried minimizing the area of uiscrollview/uiimageview but to no avail. Here is my code to add the views:

```
[self.scrollimg addSubview: self.theimg];
[self.view addSubview: self.scrollimg];
[self.view addSubview: self.segmntdctrl];
```

This shows the scrollable image but without the segmented control. They are all created through interface builder.

Thanks

Edit: More code-

```
self.theimg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
self.theimg.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill);
[self.theimg setImage:image];

self.scrollimg.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.scrollimg.delegate = self;
[self.scrollimg setContentSize:self.theimg.frame.size];
```

Comment: Updated the question with more code.. Thanks.

Comment: What about the segmented control?

Comment: I did not define anything for the segmented control besides adding it as a subview.. It was created through IB and I only linked it to a UISegmentedControl (segmntdctrl). Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `frame` for the `segmntdctrl`. Don't know how it is configured in the IB but it might have a frame that is putting it out of the visible region of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.segmntdctrl]
```

?

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the issue. Keep in mind my segmented control is not placed on the uiimageview or uiscrollview.. I made sure to put it in its own space